# Class 'MongoClient' not found in xampp

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to connect mongodb with php.

PHP version : 5.6

Mongodb:

System : 64 bit

Xampp : v3.2.1

Window : 7

I have added php_mongo.dll (as per system 64 bit) into php.ini file and copied that dll into php/ext folder.when i am trying to connect, i am getting following message.

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\
```

connection file

```
<?php


        $MongoDBConnection = new MongoClient();


    $DB = $MongoDBConnection->selectDB('SimpleCrud');


    $pessoas = $DB->pessoas;
?>
```

Comment: First, you should upgrade your PHP version to a supported one, 5.2 is very old. Then, there should be 2 copies of php.ini, one for cli and another one for apache (or other webserver), check if you edited both. Best way to check if everything is OK is creating a file wih phpinfo() inside a view it via http

Comment: how to find php.ini for cli ?

Comment: It's not important here to fine php.ini for cli, it's important to be sure to get the *correct* php.ini changed. I guess that the php.ini you need is the apache one, so my comment was just to be sure that you're editing the correct php.ini. Go with the phpinfo() and check if you find Mongo-related stuff

Comment: i didn't find any mongo-related stuff when i run the phpinfo().what should i do ?

Comment: Did you follow all instructions? See http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows

Answer (score 0):

To use MongoDB with PHP, you need to use MongoDB PHP driver. [CLICKHERE](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html) to download the driver. Make sure to download the latest release of it. Now unzip the archive and put **php_mongo.dll** in your PHP extension directory ("**C:\xampp\php\ext**" by default) and add the following line to your **php.ini** file.

```
extension = php_mongo.dll
```

Following is the code snippet to connect to the database :

```
<?php
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();

   echo "Connection to database successfully";
   // select a database
   $db = $m->myTestdb; // myTestdb-> Your Database Name

   echo "Database myTestdbselected";
?>
```

When the program is executed, it will produce the following result −

```
Connection to database successfully
Database myTestdb selected
```